# Seed recovery strategy

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, seed

I got locked out of my Ledger Nano S. When setting up the device I was given a 24 words seed passphrase, which I wrote down. The device asked me to verify 3 of the 24 words and my input was valid.

It now turned out that I made a mistake when writing the seed passphrase down since the checksum doesn't validate and I can't recover my wallets. All words that I wrote down are words that are in the [BIP32 spec words list](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39).

What strategy would you use (involving coding or not coding) to try and fix the seed passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely mistyped one or several words.
Manually trying different combinations can be a tedius process.
If I were you, I would be using seed recovery tool like [btcrecover](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover).

Are you familiar with the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? The word(s) you misstyped are most probably the one(s) with shortest Levenshtein distance to the BIP32 spec words.

Example:

> st**a**ff can easily be mistaken for st**u**ff or vice versa, since both are BIP32
>   words.

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to use btcrecover but it doesn't seem to support Segwit BTC addresses (P2SH starting with 3).